# Switching Themes in Drupal 7 module (mobile tools)

Tags: drupal-7

I've been trying to get mobile_tools for Drupal 7 to work but it appears it's not switching themes. (Or at least I can't get it to switch).

This is the code "in charge of changing to the mobile theme. If I print $custom_theme it does become the name of the mobile theme but the displayed theme is still the default. I have not been able to find any documentation on variable $custom_theme at least not for Drupal 7.

```
/**
 * Being called in the hook_boot() implementation
 * This function is in charge of changing to the mobile theme
 */
function mobile_tools_switch_theme($device) {
 global $custom_theme, $conf;
 // check if theme switching is forced
 $current_url_type = mobile_tools_is_mobile_site();

 if (($current_url_type == 'mobile' &&  variable_get('mobile-tools-theme-switch', ''  ) == 'mobile-tools-mobile-url') || 
   (variable_get('mobile-tools-theme-switch', ''  ) == 'mobile-tools-mobile-device' && $device['type']  == 'mobile') ) {
  $group = $device['group'];
  $mobile_detection_module = variable_get('mobile-tools-device-detection', 'mobile_tools');
  if (variable_get($mobile_detection_module . '_' . $group . '_enable', '') == 1) {
   $custom_theme = variable_get($mobile_detection_module . '_' . $group . '_theme', $conf['theme_default']);
   return TRUE;
  }
  else {
   $custom_theme  = variable_get('mobile_tools_theme_name', $conf['theme_default']);
   return TRUE;
  }
 }
 return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$custom_theme` is no longuer the way to switch themes in Drupal 7 as mentionned in the [Upgrade modules from 6.x to 7.x](http://drupal.org/node/224333#custom_theme) page, you have to use [hook_custom_theme](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_custom_theme/7) or specify a `theme callback` for the path instead.

---

Example from the [upgrade page](http://drupal.org/node/224333#custom_theme):

```
<?php
/**
* Implements hook_menu_alter().
*/
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  // Set the theme callback function for all node pages. As per the
  // standard behavior for hook_menu() properties, this will be
  // inherited by all paths underneath node/%node as well, unless
  // they define their own theme callback.
  $items['node/%node']['theme callback'] = 'mymodule_default_node_theme';

  // Set a different theme callback for node edit pages, and pass
  // along the node object to this function so we can make decisions
  // based on it.
  $items['node/%node/edit']['theme callback'] = 'mymodule_edit_node_theme';
  $items['node/%node/edit']['theme arguments'] = array(1);
}

/**
* Defaults to using the 'some_theme' theme for node pages.
*/
function mymodule_default_node_theme() {
  return 'some_theme';
}

/**
* For editing page nodes, uses the 'some_other_theme' theme.
*/
function mymodule_edit_node_theme($node) {
  return $node->type == 'page' ? 'some_other_theme' : mymodule_default_node_theme();
}

/**
* Implements hook_custom_theme().
*/
function mymodule_custom_theme() {
  global $user;
  // If the current user has a special role assigned to them, then display all
  // pages of the site (including those listed above) using the 'special_theme'
  // theme.
  if (in_array(variable_get('mymodule_special_role', 0), array_keys($user->roles))) {
    return 'special_theme';
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: I will give it a try an post back. As a temp work around I have installed the switchtheme module and changed the `$custom_theme` to `$_SESSION['custom_theme']` which switch theme uses to switch themes but it doesn't do it on the first page request meaning switchtheme module is called before mobile_tools

Comment: Ok so there seems to be some issues on top of that basics. if l() is called by another module before the hook_custom_theme module it can no longer change the theme because it's been initiated. So you have to change module weights and make sure the module that changes themes is among the first. I had trouble even after changing module weights so I just disabled all extra modules and tested it (it worked) then I just enabled one or two modules at a time. By the time I had all modules back up it kept working so I'm not sure how that worked out but it did so far. hope it helps someone else.